# Determining ToolStripButton CheckState from ToolStrip loop

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.Net toolstrip to which I add buttons programmatically. Some of the buttons are checked or unchecked depending on the state they were left in when the user last set up the application (from values stored in the Registry:

```
Dim OneButton As New ToolStripButton("T", Nothing, Nothing, "Thailandr")
OneButton.CheckOnClick = True
AddHandler OneButton.Click, AddressOf ClickHandlerLayers
tsLayers.Items.Add(OneButton)
If GetSetting(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath), "Settings", "ThailandSetting", False) Then
    OneButton.PerformClick()
End If    

OneButton = New ToolStripButton("W", Nothing, Nothing, "World")
OneButton.CheckOnClick = True
AddHandler OneButton.Click, AddressOf ClickHandlerLayers
tsLayers.Items.Add(OneButton)
If GetSetting(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath), "Settings", "WorldSetting", False) Then
    OneButton.PerformClick()
End If
```

Everything works fine except that I want to save the values of the buttons back into the Registry when the user clicks the Apply button. I want to save the values by looping through the tsLayers toolstrip rather than hard coding (which is possible, but is extra work when I add more buttons). So far I can see the names an

```
   ' Save which background layers are to be used
    For Each tb As ToolStripItem In tsLayers.Items
        Debug.Print(tb.Name)
        Debug.Print(tb.GetType.ToString)
        Debug.Print(tb.Selected)
        Debug.Print(tb.Pressed)

    Next
```

Results are:

```
Thailand
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton
False
False

World
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton
False
False
```

even if one of the buttons is pressed/checked at the time of looking at the results. I can't see any other properties that can help me, nor any collections that I can burrow into.

Is there a way to determine the checkState of a toolstripbutton in a toolstrip by looping through the toolstrip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the `ToolStripItem` as a `ToolStripButton` and you'll have access to the `CheckState` property

```
        If tb.GetType Is GetType(ToolStripButton) Then
            Dim tbCast As ToolStripButton = DirectCast(tb, ToolStripButton)
            Debug.Print(tbCast.CheckState)
        End If
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much. I am now able to save the toolbutton status for the whole toolbar to the Registry by just adding a line:

    SaveSetting(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath), "Settings", tb.Name, tbCast.CheckState)